# Passing function as a prop results in an error?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, types

I'm passing a function (toggleFavoriteAction) to my RecipeListItem component as a prop. When I click on the button to call the function, I get this error: TypeError: toggleFavoriteAction is not a function. But toggleFavoriteAction is indeed a function.

[image]

```
// RecipeList
const toggleFavoriteAction = (recipe: RecipeConfig) => {
    return favorites.includes(recipe)
      ? dispatch(addToFavorites(recipe))
      : dispatch(removeFromFavorites(recipe));
  };

  const props = {
    toggleFavoriteAction,
    favorites,
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {recipes.results &&
        Array.isArray(recipes.results) &&
        recipes.results.map((data: RecipeConfig, key: number) => (
          <div key={key}>
            <RecipeListItem {...data} {...props} />
          </div>
        ))}
    </div>
  );
```

```
// RecipeListItem
const RecipeListItem = (recipe: RecipeConfig, props: any): JSX.Element => {
  const { toggleFavoriteAction, favorites } = props;
...
......
  <button onClick={() => toggleFavoriteAction(recipe)}> // this button
     {favorites && favorites.find((fav: any) => fav.id === recipe.id)
       ? 'Remove from fav'
       : 'Add to fav'}
  </button>
```

Comment: I think `RecipeConfig` is also parts of the `props` object and there should be no second parameter, probably your `props` would be undefined in this case

Comment: I kinda try that already, I couldn't map the recipes.results that way.

Comment: Do you use Redux ? I think the problem is in how you use dispatch. Do you connect your store to the component ? Is dispatch defined ?

Comment: Yep, I'm using Redux. dispatch is defined (const dispatch=useDispatch()), and it is connected to the store.

Comment: Can you log `toggleFavoriteAction` on button click? The error says it is not a function, this would give us a hint what it actually is.

Comment: Still the same error, I think this might be a typescript error, Im getting this from the lint: 'toggleFavoriteAction' is missing in props validation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is in how you access to properties

```
// RecipeListItem
const RecipeListItem = (recipe: RecipeConfig, props: any): JSX.Element => { //here is wrong
  const { toggleFavoriteAction, favorites } = props;
...
......
  <button onClick={() => toggleFavoriteAction(recipe)}> // this button
     {favorites && favorites.find((fav: any) => fav.id === recipe.id)
       ? 'Remove from fav'
       : 'Add to fav'}
  </button>
```

should be

```
// RecipeListItem
const RecipeListItem = (props: any): JSX.Element => {
  
  const { toggleFavoriteAction, favorites, recipe } = props;
...
......
  <button onClick={() => toggleFavoriteAction(recipe)}> // this button
     {favorites && favorites.find((fav: any) => fav.id === recipe.id)
       ? 'Remove from fav'
       : 'Add to fav'}
  </button>
```

both {...data} and {...props} that you pass to

```
 <RecipeListItem {...data} {...props} />
```

are props

And you can access by the first argument of the react component

```
const RecipeListItem = (props: any): JSX.Element => {
....
```

Comment: With this approach, my recipe is now undefined.

Comment: because you're spreading `data` so you would not be able to access it as `recipe` if you want to do that, you can destructure your props in a way that any remaining properties go into the recipe object, i.e. `let { toggleFavoriteAction, favorites, ...recipe } = props`

Comment: The answer is ok, but don't spead data: `<RecipeListItem recipe={data} {...props} />`